# looking for a way to efficiently multiply members of lists in a special manner

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have some lists that I use their members in some function `f(t,x)` in this way:

```
k= [0]*6

a=[1/4,3/8,12/13,1,1/2]
b=[[1/4],[3/32,9/32],[1932/2197,-7200/2197,7296/2197],[439/216,-8,3680/513,-845/4104],[-8/27,2,-3544/2565,1859/4104,-11/40]]
R=[1/360,-128/4275,-2197/75240,1/50,2/55]
c=[25/216,1408/2565,2197/4104,-1/5]
            
k[0] = h * f(t, x)
k[1] = h * f(t + a[0] * h, x + b[0][0] * k[0] )
k[2] = h * f(t + a[1] * h, x + b[1][0] * k[0] + b[1][1] * k[1])
k[3] = h * f(t + a[2] * h, x + b[2][0] * k[0] + b[2][1] * k[1] + b[2][2] * k[2])
k[4] = h * f(t + a[3] * h, x + b[3][0] * k[0] + b[3][1] * k[1] + b[3][2] * k[2] + b[3][3] * k[3])
k[5] = h * f(t + a[4] * h, x + b[4][0] * k[0] + b[4][1] * k[1] + b[4][2] * k[2] + b[4][3] * k[3] + b[4][4] * k[4])
```

Where `h` is just a constant. But this just looks like a matrix multiplication (maybe?) but I'm not sure. I have two major questions: is it possible to represent this using matrix multiplication (or even numpy array multiplication) and if so, is it faster and more efficient?

Comment: Is this for an RK45 method? If so, no it is not just a matrix multiply, each of the subsequent values of `k` build upon the previous operation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method

Comment: @CoryKramer Yes. Then is there a way to calculate this more efficiently?

Comment: In other words notice `k[1]` depends on `k[0]`, then `k[2]` depends on both `k[1]` and `k[0]` etc

Comment: Basically what you have coded up is about as good as it gets. You could consider using the scipy implementation, you may notice performance improvements from that https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html